# How to return to a page from another page?

Tags: asp.net

I have called a method which redirects to another page. After completion of another page I want to come back from the previous page. This is my code:

```
private string RedirectToPaymentGateway_v3(string MTrackid, string MAmount,string MSType)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["pgMTrackid"] = MTrackid;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["pgMAmount"] = MAmount;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["pgMStype"] = MSType;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("DoPost.asp", true);

    return "";
}
```

After finishing the `dopost.asp` I want to return in the page where I called `DoPost.asp`.

Comment: Try this `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("DoPost.asp", false);`

Answer (score 0):

Pass the origin page as a parameter and redirect to it afterwards:

```
private string RedirectToPaymentGateway_v3(string MTrackid, string MAmount,string MSType)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["pgMTrackid"] = MTrackid;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["pgMAmount"] = MAmount;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["pgMStype"] = MSType;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("DoPost.asp?ReturnUrl=" + 
Server.UrlEncode(Request.Url.ToString());

    return "";
}
```

and then after processing in DoPost.asp do

```
Response.Redirect(Server.UrlDecode(Request.Querystring["ReturnUrl"]));
```